# Показать размер директорий из списка

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, unix, search

Столкнулся с такой задачей.

Дан список из имен директорий *dir_list*, которые нужно найти и удалить. Для отчетности требуется предварительно сохранить в файл список со следующими параметрами:

```
РАЗМЕР ИМЯ ВРЕМЯ_МОДИФИКАЦИИ
```

Пока что приходится в ручную редактировать вывод

```
~# while read dir; do find /library -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "$dir" -print0 | xargs -0 du -hs; done < dir_list

~# while read dir; do find /library -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "$dir" -printf "%f %c\n"; done < dir_list
```

Система Ubuntu GNU/Linux со стандартным набором утилит. Оболочка - bash. Объём поиска 20.0ТБ.

Comment: Размер чего? Вместо `du -hs` пишите скрипт в `{ ... }`. Время берётся из `stat`.

Comment: @0andriy размер занимаемый на диске.

Comment: Это не ответ на вопрос. Почему? Подумайте сами — отличное задание для немного более глубокого понимания об ФС и данных. А ответ на ваш вопрос фактически у меня в первом комментарии.

Comment: Дело в том, что нужна дополнительная информация в одном списке. Я прогоняю два поиска потом суммирую в редакторе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вызов программ *find/xargs* здесь явно излишен.

обёртку в виде цикла можно представить примерно так (здесь `report` — файл с отчётом):

```
$ while read d; do dir="/library/$d"; ...; done < dir_list > report
```

а вместо двоеточия надо выполнить два действия:

1. получение данных для отчёта. например, так:

   ```
   stat --printf="$(du -hs "$dir") %y\n" "$dir"
   ```
2. собственно удаление каталога. например, так:

   ```
   rm -rf "$dir"
   ```

---

итого в одну строку:

```
$ while read d; do dir="/library/$d"; stat --printf="$(du -hs "$dir") %y\n" "$dir"; rm -rf "$dir"; done < dir_list > report
```

---

пример (каталоги намеренно содержат пробел в имени, для демонстрации: так тоже работает):

```
$ cat dir_list
a b
c d
$ while read d; do dir="/library/$d"; stat --printf="$(du -hs "$dir") %y\n" "$dir"; rm -rf "$dir"; done < dir_list > report
$ cat report 
4.0K    /library/a b 2017-07-07 01:53:55.109088360 +0300
4.0K    /library/c d 2017-07-07 02:09:00.533072146 +0300
```

Comment: @alexander_barakin гляну завтра. find нужен так как *dir_list* содержит имена директорий, а не полные пути. они могут быть разбросанны по дереву где угодно.

Comment: в примере у вас просматривается лишь непосредственное содержимое каталога `/library`. исходя из этой информации я и писал ответ.

Comment: @alexander_barakins за пункт 1. отдельное спасибо, думал форматирование подлерживает только % дироективы.